# How to use binaries in jailshell?

Tags: centos, binary, jails

I'm offering jailshell (on CentOS- whm) access to someone in order to use the folder sync tool called Unison (Some sort of bidirectional rsync)

That's for the background.

Unison is installed, as soon as I type unison in my terminal, I get the Usage list of unison.

But when I log in into my jail shell, and run the same app, it just returns

```
-jailshell: unison : command not found
```

However, when I look into the jailshell from a root perspective : 
[/home/virtfs/username/usr/bin] I can see a binary named unison@
Looks like the bin folder is an alias.

Why isn't it recognized in the jailshell? and how can I access this binary from the jailshell ?

### Edits

result of ls -l /usr/bin/unison (both in and outside)

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 24 20 déc 08:36 /usr/bin/unison -> /etc/alternatives/unison
```

result of ldd /usr/bin/unison inside:

```
no file or folder of this type (translated)
```

and outside : juste lists a bunch of libraries

result of ./unison from inside /usr/bin :

```
no file or folder of this type (translated)
```

Comment: IMO, the shell can't find it in the PATH. What's the output of `echo PATH` in the jailshell, and can you go directly to where the binary is and execute it from the jailshell `cd /usr/bin && ./unison`?

Comment: Post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/unison` and `ldd /usr/bin/unison` from inside the jail, and the corresponding commands outside the jail.

Comment: just added the different results in the op

Comment: Looks like `unison` is a soft link from the jailshell perspective. can you give the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/unison`

Comment: Ok Now I looked at your updated question. Can u please verify that `/etc/alternatives/unison` exists?

Comment: not from within the jail, from root's perspective, it exists. alternatives folders doesn't exist for the jailed user